# Neighbors of a given matrix cell

Tags: scala, matrix

Suppose I need to enumerate all neighbors of a given cell in `Vector[Vector[Int]]`

```
type Matrix = Vector[Vector[Int]]
def neighbors(i: Int, j: Int, m: Matrix): Seq[Int] = ???
```

I am writing `neighbors` like that:

```
def neighbors(i: Int, j: Int, m: Matrix): Seq[Int] = for {
  dx <- -1 to 1
  dy <- -1 to 1
  if (dx | dy) != 0 && m.indices.contains(i + dx) && m(i).indices.contains(j + dy)
} yield m(i + dx)(j + dy)
```

This implementation looks Ok but a bit awkward. Could you suggest a better solution ?

Comment: You can simplify `.indices.contains(...)` to the more direct `.isDefinedAt(...)`.

Comment: Good point. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Not simple - used lift

```
def neighbors(i: Int, j: Int, m: Matrix): Seq[Int] = (-1 to 1).flatMap {
    y => (-1 to 1).map { x => (x, y) }
  }.withFilter {
    case (x, y) => x != 0 || y != 0
  }.flatMap {
    case (x, y) => m.lift(i).flatMap(x => x.lift(y))
  }
```